# Cross section or panel data?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, panel-data, stata, cross-section

I am studying cross-border merger and the post merger peformance differences between when the target firm is in developed country versus developing country. For dependent variable, I am planning to collect the growth rate of profit after tax (profit change from before 2 years to after 2 years, checking consolidated financial summary), independent variable is dummy (developing or developed). I am wondering whether my data set is the cross sectional data or panel data (e.g,merger happened in 2004 but i will check 2002 and 2006 financial summary and calculate the percentage change and put it in the dataset)?

Comment: The answer depends on the structure of the data. If there is information collected for multiple firms across multiple time periods then it is a panel data structure. If there are multiple firms' information aggregated into a single period, then it's cross-sectional.